# dataGridView Selected Row Exception

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have an array filled with strings, originating from text files selected by the user. For every additional file that is read, the array

```
public string[,] pumps;
```

gets additional data. After the reading of a new file, the whole data read so far has to be displyed by a table. I managed to use the dataGridView as follows for this purpose:

```
    private void ShowTablePumpsOverview()
    {

        var rowLength = 4;

            var row = new DataGridViewRow();

            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < rowLength; ++columnIndex)
            {
                    row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() { Value = pumps[read_files, columnIndex] });
            }

        dataGridView_files_overview.ColumnCount = rowLength;
        dataGridView_files_overview.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

So far this works fine although it might not be elegant since I'm a beginner in C# programming. When I'm running the programm I can click into the Table an the corresponding row turns blue. Now I just want to know to Index of this blue row. After trying a lot of suggested solutions to this problem like

```
        int Row = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

I'm still perplexed since I always get System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException.
Can anyone explain to me why this happens and how I can fix it?

Comment: If `SelectionMode` property of your dataGridView1 is not set to `FullRowSelect` or `RowHeaderSelect` there are no selected rows. If you want to just select a desired cell then just use `CurrentCell` property. This is the currently selected cell and it has a property for the row. Please set selectionmode property or use currentcell property.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but the selction mode is already FullRowSelect.

Comment: Can you give the properties set for the datagridview in designer code? Is your datagridview virtualmode set to true? where do you call `this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;`

Comment: I would like to give you the whole set of properties, but I don't know how to change from the GUI access of the properties to designer code. However, I saw the following entry: Row Template - DataGridViewRow { Index=-1 }. This might be a problem ... .   The virtual mode was et to false. Turning it to true did not help. I call the directly this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index; in the method private void button_Grid_Count_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) which is directly located in the main programm (public partial class Form1 : Form).